# Verdier (w) condition implies the $w_f$ condition when the restriction of $f$ in each stratum is a submersion?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, resolution-of-singularities

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be and let $\Theta=(X_\beta)_{\beta\in I}$ a Verdier stratification for X. Let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial function, such that $f_{|_{X_\beta}}$ is submersion for all $\beta\in I$. If $X_\beta\subset \overline{X}_\alpha\setminus X_\alpha$. Then the pair $(X_\alpha, X_\beta)$ satisfies the $W_f$ condition.